# Return zero in a count query with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, null

In my table of repairs, i want count cars in each status (1,2,3 and 4):

```
Status 1: 5
Status 2: 0
Status 3: 6
Status 4: 3
```

As it shows, no cars on status 2, so, i did the same query 4 times with "WHEN status == 'n' to count in each status, and works fine.

Now i want to do in only one query, but in my query:

> select status,count(car_id) from `repairs` GROUP BY status.

show me this:

```
Status 1: 5
Status 3: 6
Status 4: 3
```

Comment: Are `status` and `repairs` stored in separate tables?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I only have one table, repairs, that contains car_id's and an status row that contain a int number, 1-2-3 or 4.

Comment: Are you sure you have status 2 in your table.

Comment: there is no records with cars on status == 2, so it returns me a null result instead of "0" @FahadAnjum

Comment: It means like it is showing status 2 : null.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but I think you have a typo in your test. "GROUP BY car_id" should be "GROUP BY status" as you want a count per status.

Comment: Yes, Im using a while sentence: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "Status ".$row['status'],": $row['count(car_id)']"; } @FahadAnjum

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a source, probably a table, which contains every status which you want to appear in the report.  One way would be the "calendar table" approach where you join a table containing every status to your current query, e.g.

```
SELECT
    t1.status,
    COALESCE(t2.car_cnt, 0) AS car_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS status UNION ALL   -- replace this ad-hoc subquery with
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL             -- an actual "calendar" table of statuses
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL             -- or if you already have such a table, use that
    SELECT 4
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT status, COUNT(car_id) AS car_cnt
    FROM repairs
    GROUP BY car_id
) t2
    ON t1.status = t2.status
```

Comment: Given that the question is also tagged 'PHP', I view this as a less appropriate solution

Comment: @Strawberry And I disagree with you.  Not having necessary data to answer business queries has little to do with the application language.  Unless you are suggesting to handle this from PHP, which I think is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT status, count(car_id) 
FROM repairs GROUP BY car_id 
UNION 
SELECT status, 0
FROM repairs WHERE status NOT IN 
(SELECT status FROM repairs GROUP BY car_id);
```